# pub/sub synchronous pull w deadline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

```
from google.api_core import retry
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1    

NUM_MESSAGES = 1

with subscriber:
         response = subscriber.pull(request={"subscription": subscription_path, "max_messages": NUM_MESSAGES},retry=retry.Retry(deadline=120),)
```

Requirement is to wait for X (120) seconds for the message to arrive in subscription, read it & validate some fields in it. Somehow, above code snippet was NOT working w.r.t deadline . It's not waiting for 120 seconds and timing out much before . what am I missing !?

ref: [pub/sub synchronous pull w deadline](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull)

Comment: If the message is in the topic it should be ready to be pulled. The retry parameter is here to ensure that any non acked message will get resent after this deadline I guess.

Comment: You didn't follow the link in reference. You must use a subscription pull future with a timeout. Here the retry is for the message retrying delay in case of nack.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere .   But , I have a restriction on no:of messages . I just want to read 1 message at a time from subscription & process / validate it accordingly . Believe in that case - its synchronous pull . rt?

Comment: You have parameters to specify the message flow of the subscriber: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#flow_control

Comment: Hi @gthy, Did the above comments help you in resolving the issue? If you have resolved the issue, can you add the resolution steps as an answer to this question.

Comment: I am also trying to use PubSub synchronous pull but reading on web that it has got a very high latency. How much is the average latency for a synchronous pull?

Answer (score 0):

As Guillaume mentioned, the [timeout](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/17b5d143f2ffcab7e7efea8bb2018148c00ce1ee/google/pubsub_v1/services/subscriber/client.py#L1032) argument should be used how long the Pull request is open for. The default timeout looks to be [60 seconds](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/17b5d143f2ffcab7e7efea8bb2018148c00ce1ee/google/pubsub_v1/services/subscriber/transports/base.py#L247).

So, you could write:

```
response = subscriber.pull(request={"subscription": subscription_path, "max_messages": NUM_MESSAGES},timeout=120.0,)
```